# Swift - Core Data group by date when pulling another attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have the following Entity model (name and data type) in Core Data:

1. Item - String
2. Timestamp - Date
3. Value - Double

Is there any way to fetch the equivalent of "select date(timestamp) as date_value, sum(value) from Entity group by date_value, value"?

Googling on groupings doesn't explain how to do this with the Date type very clearly. I tried a workaround by adding a new column called date_string where it's a formatted String version of the Timestamp column, like '2018-03-19', but it doesn't seem very elegant and doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t do this while fetching when using Core Data but rather fetch all relevant objects and then do the grouping and summation in your code.

I would use a dictionary with dictionaries for this, date (as string) as key and double as value for the inner dictionary and the item property as key and the inner dictionary as value for the outer dictionary. Or alternatively create a summation structure and use that in a single dictionary.